# Mysql query optimization takes more than 30 sec

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Hi friends  can any one please help me to optimize this query ,it takes more than 30 sec.
any suggestion is warmly welcome.

Query :

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CCD.CONTACT_FIRST_NAME, ' ', CCD.CONTACT_LAST_NAME) AS NAME,
    A.EMAIL_IDS,
    CCD.UNSUBSCRIBE,
    IFNULL(CSL.LOG_DATE, '') AS LOG_DATE,
    CSL.IP_ADDRESS,
    IF(CSL.BROWSER IS NULL, '', CSL.BROWSER) AS BROWSER,
    (CASE
        WHEN (UNSUBSCRIBE = 0 OR UNSUBSCRIBE IS NULL) THEN 'Opted In'
        ELSE (CASE
            WHEN (UNSUBSCRIBE = 1) THEN 'Opted Out'
            ELSE (CASE
                WHEN
                    ((UNSUBSCRIBE = 2 OR UNSUBSCRIBE = 3)
                        AND CCD.CONTACT_ID NOT IN (SELECT 
                            CONTACT_ID
                        FROM
                            CM_SUBSCRIPTION_MAIL_DATA
                        WHERE
                            IS_MAIL_SENT = 'Y'))
                THEN
                    'Opt-In Request not Sent'
                ELSE 'Opt-In Pending'
            END)
        END)
    END) AS CURR_SUB,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSCRIBE_FROM = 0) THEN 'Opted In'
        ELSE (CASE
            WHEN (SUBSCRIBE_FROM = 1) THEN 'Opted Out'
            ELSE (CASE
                WHEN (SUBSCRIBE_FROM = 2 OR SUBSCRIBE_FROM = 3) THEN 'Opt-In Pending'
                ELSE ''
            END)
        END)
    END) AS SUB_FROM,
    SUBSCRIBE_FROM,
    (CASE
        WHEN (SUBSCRIBE_TO = 0) THEN 'Opted In'
        ELSE (CASE
            WHEN (SUBSCRIBE_TO = 1) THEN 'Opted Out'
            ELSE (CASE
                WHEN (SUBSCRIBE_TO = 2 OR SUBSCRIBE_TO = 3) THEN 'Opt-In Pending'
                ELSE ''
            END)
        END)
    END) AS SUB_TO,
    SUBSCRIBE_TO
FROM
    CM_CONTACT_DETAILS CCD
        LEFT JOIN
    ADDRESS A ON CCD.CONTACT_ID = A.FOREIGN_ID
        LEFT JOIN
    CM_SUBSCRIPTION_LOGS CSL ON CSL.CONTACT_ID = CCD.CONTACT_ID
WHERE
    1 = 1
GROUP BY CSL.LOG_DATE , CCD.CONTACT_ID
ORDER BY NAME DESC , LOG_DATE DESC
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case/when can be simplified, but I believe the killer of your query was the correlated NOT IN SELECT clause for your Opt-in request not sent.

I've change your query to do a left-join to your mailing table based on the contact AND the mailed status of "Y".  So this simplifies your case to only have to check for IS NULL of the mailing table contact ID.

You can't do too much on performance since your Group by is by columns from different tables that won't take advantage of any index optimization, then all that ordered by the name makes it more of an issue... but the correlated subquery per the field being executed every time to a left-join SHOULD help.

```
SELECT 
      CONCAT(CCD.CONTACT_FIRST_NAME, ' ', CCD.CONTACT_LAST_NAME) AS NAME,
      A.EMAIL_IDS,
      CCD.UNSUBSCRIBE,
      IFNULL(CSL.LOG_DATE, '') AS LOG_DATE,
      CSL.IP_ADDRESS,
      IF(CSL.BROWSER IS NULL, '', CSL.BROWSER) AS BROWSER,
      CASE WHEN UNSUBSCRIBE = 0 OR UNSUBSCRIBE IS NULL THEN 'Opted In'
           WHEN UNSUBSCRIBE = 1 THEN 'Opted Out'
           WHEN UNSUBSCRIBE IN (2,3) AND SMD.CONTACT_ID IS NULL THEN 'Opt-In Request not Sent'
           ELSE 'Opt-In Pending' END AS CURR_SUB,
      CASE WHEN SUBSCRIBE_FROM = 0 THEN 'Opted In'
           WHEN SUBSCRIBE_FROM = 1 THEN 'Opted Out'
           WHEN SUBSCRIBE_FROM = 2 OR SUBSCRIBE_FROM = 3 THEN 'Opt-In Pending'
           ELSE '' END AS SUB_FROM,
      SUBSCRIBE_FROM,
      CASE WHEN SUBSCRIBE_TO = 0 THEN 'Opted In'
           WHEN SUBSCRIBE_TO = 1 THEN 'Opted Out'
           WHEN SUBSCRIBE_TO = 2 OR SUBSCRIBE_TO = 3 THEN 'Opt-In Pending'
           ELSE '' END AS SUB_TO,
      SUBSCRIBE_TO
   FROM
      CM_CONTACT_DETAILS CCD
         LEFT JOIN ADDRESS A 
            ON CCD.CONTACT_ID = A.FOREIGN_ID
         LEFT JOIN CM_SUBSCRIPTION_LOGS CSL 
            ON CSL.CONTACT_ID = CCD.CONTACT_ID
         LEFT JOIN CM_SUBSCRIPTION_MAIL_DATA SMD
            ON CCD.CONTACT_ID = SMD.CONTACT_ID
            AND IS_MAIL_SENT = 'Y'
   WHERE
      1 = 1
   GROUP BY 
      CSL.LOG_DATE, 
      CCD.CONTACT_ID
   ORDER BY 
      NAME DESC, 
      LOG_DATE DESC
   LIMIT 
      0, 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your time , but till now it takes 21 sec, any other suggestions plz.

Comment: @susantomahato, without more detail of tables, indexes and why of the group by, order by and limit, not much... The limit FORCES ALL records to be returned and ordered before the limit of 20 can be accounted for, so it MUST process all rows.